# Google App Engine: 1000 records limit still present with JPA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

The new [release 1.3.1 of GAE](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/02/app-engine-sdk-131-including-major.html) has dropped the 1000 records limit:

> **No more 1000 result limit** - That's
>   right: with addition of Cursors and
>   the culmination of many smaller
>   Datastore stability and performance
>   improvements over the last few months,
>   we're now confident enough to remove
>   the maximum result limit altogether.

However, the [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) link to a [detail description](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Query_Cursors) which does not mention JPA, only JDO and the low level API:

> In JDO, you can use an extension and
>   the JDOCursorHelper class to use
>   cursors with JDO queries.

JPA is not mentioned, and my tests using `query.setFirstResult(n)` still show the same error messages if n is greater than 1000.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset may not be above
1000
        at
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java: 33)
        at
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeSyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:
60)
        at
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.runQuery(PreparedQueryImpl.java:
115) ...
```

**select count(*)**:

I also found that a `select count(*) from MyEntity` which has more than 1000 instances returns 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release 1.3.6 removed the limits:

**Version 1.3.6 - August 17, 2010**

> Results of datastore count() queries
>   and offsets for all datastore queries
>   are no longer capped at 1000.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

JDO "extensions" in that "detail description" equates to JPA "hints" on the query, so why not set that same hint for a JPA query?

Cursor cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
query.setHint(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);

Comment: I will try this. So to solve the count(*) problem (see my update), this means I will have to iterate over Cursors, or use the low level API?

Answer (score 0):

I am using JPA to access google datastore and able to fetch more then 3000 records at a time. I dont think that limit is still exist.