# Objectify 3. Error to generate statistics with query.count: "offset may not be above 1000"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

We have an application with Google App Engine (GAE), App Engine Datastore and Objectify v3 (to access to the database).
We generate statistics for every user and the queries to generate them are like:

```
ofy() //
.query(Entity.class) //
.filter("owner in ", keyUsers)
.count();
```

Where **keyUsers** is a list of Key.

Few days ago all this kind of queries started to throw exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset may not be above 1000
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.peekQueryResultAndIfFirstRecordIndexList(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:161)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:104)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureInitialized(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:130)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.getNumSkipped(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:171)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.countEntities(PreparedQueryImpl.java:109)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.count(QueryImpl.java:410)
```

Even when **keyUsers** has one key it throws an exception.
We have many records (more than one thousand) in every Entity but the result is always less than 100.

We've solved temporarily the problem adding a limit to every query:

```
ofy() //
.query(Entity.class) //
.filter("owner in ", keyUsers)
.limit(1000)
.count();
```

But It's not the ideal way to solve it.

I've got two questions:

- What is the problem? I've found this [Google App Engine: 1000 records limit still present with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264731/google-app-engine-1000-records-limit-still-present-with-jpa) but I'm not sure if this is the problem because I couldn't reproduce the issue in locahost.
- How to solve it in a better way.

Comment: Are you aware that count is NOT efficient at all? Read the docs on count, it will take time proportional to the query size and will timeout on large lists. Its the wrong way to do stats. You need to maintain your counters yourself. Its also suspicious that you get the offset issue as if count was looping through fixed pages by offset instead of index pages.

Comment: I just have begun to have the same issue as you. Not very helpful, just wanted you to know that you are not alone :-) Our code have been stable for 6 months so this must be a change on GAE that triggers it.

Comment: I just removed log.info("q3=" + q3.count()); and then the error went away so it seems it is the count() that is the problem and not the result itself.

Comment: This is best posted in the GAE google group - it's a GAE issue, not an Objectify issue.

Comment: @stickfigure can you please provide a link. We are also hit by this issue suddenly

Comment: What kind of link are you looking for? Objectify's `count()` simply calls the underlying `PreparedQuery.countEntities()` method. If the low level API is producing an error, post to the GAE list.

Comment: Google App Engine group is moving to StackOverflow. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/8zQtq_m9W5w)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It started all of a sudden without any code change on our side. Anyone figured out why?

Comment: It also happens to me in a query with an "IN" operator...